# Laravel Dompdf error 'Image not found or type unknown'

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf

I have a problem to show image that is in public folder.

My PDF print is in not in blade, it is in helper folder. Can that be the issue? I attached below two images of my code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: welcome to so, upload your code snippet in here not in image, see [how to ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: also try to return $html, see if image loads in $html

Answer (score 1):

please post you images here, not external links, how ever.

if you use a relative path to the images, the pdf loader don't know where load the file, so you have to use an absolute route, you can use the helper `asset()` to reference the public folder files

```php
asset('images/raxca_logo.png')
```

also make sure in your `.env`file you hace the correct url in the `APP_URL` variable

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I added it to my code and still doesn't work. This is how it looks like now.                                                                                                            
         $html.='<img src="<img src="'.asset('images/raca_logo.jpg').'">';                                                               this is my APP_URL:   APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: use only ....<img src="{{asset('images/raca_logo.jpg')}}">

Answer (score 1):

According to this question you have to use the full server path try:

```
<img src="{{ public_path("storage/images/apple.png") }}" alt="" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
```

**Note:**
Image must save in the public folder only